# How much Positive Survey needed to reach 75% target

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula to understand how much positive survey is need without any negative survey to reach a certain target.

the sample sheet.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far on your end? Also, it would help if you can provide at least one sample calculation as to how to get the positive survey that's needed based on at least of of the rows on your sample data for better understanding.

Comment: You have also not shown the sheet name, row numbers or column letters. So writing a formula that would be easy for you to apply to your real sheet would not be very efficient. And you have added tags for both `excel-formula` and `google-sheets-formula`; but Excel and Google Sheets are not the same, and so the function lists and resulting formulas would not be the same. Please choose one tag or the other. And consider sharing a link to an editable sample spreadsheet, in addition to Irvin's request above.

Comment: Really, what you are asking is an math/algebra question, not a question about Google Sheets functionality. In other words, it appears that you are asking someone here to figure out the math problem for you, and then to tell you how to write that math equation in Google Sheets. And that isn't really the intent of these forums. If you already know the math equation as it would be done on paper, show that in your post. (Many volunteer contributors here, including myself, are smart enough to figure that out on our own; but that isn't the goal of these forums.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you're looking for is the following. In the future, you should include things like how you calculate Customer Satisfaction, what you've tried, and the column and row headers so people can reference the ranges exactly.

The formula I'm writing I expect to sit on the side outside of this table, so it will tell you how many Positive reviews are needed to reach 75% satisfaction, assuming satisfaction is `Positive / sum (positive, negative)`

`= ( [Negative Feedback] / .25 ) - [Negative Feedback]`

That figures that denominator needed to get negative feedback to 25%, then takes the inverse of that.